# Get Hierarchy Data in Python

Tags: python, networkx

I have the data:

| issue | father | son |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | 34 |
| 1 | 34 | 35 |
| 2 | 33 | 34 |

This script in Python retrieve the table in hierarchy:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='father', target='son', create_using=nx.DiGraph ,edge_attr=True)
print(G.out_degree())
roots = [v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0]
leaves = [v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0]
all_paths = []
for root in roots:
    for leaf in leaves:
        paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaf)
        all_paths.extend(paths)
for node in nx.nodes_with_selfloops(G):
    all_paths.append([node, node])
df_h=pd.DataFrame(sorted(all_paths)).add_prefix('Value_Depend_On_ID_').fillna('')
df_h=df_h.replace('',np.nan, regex=True)
df_h.astype('Int64')
```

the output:

| Value_Depend_On_ID_0 | Value_Depend_On_ID_1 | Value_Depend_On_ID_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 34 | 35 |

the desired output:

| Value_Depend_On_ID_0 | Value_Depend_On_ID_1 | Value_Depend_On_ID_2 | issue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 34 | 35 | 1 |
| 33 | 34 | null | 2 |

How can I add the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to group the dataframe by `issue` and then search for all paths:

```py
import networkx as nx


def group_func(g):
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
        g, source="father", target="son", create_using=nx.DiGraph
    )

    roots = [v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0]
    leaves = [v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0]

    all_paths = []
    for root in roots:
        for leaf in leaves:
            paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaf)
            all_paths.extend(paths)

    out = []
    for p in all_paths:
        d = {}
        for i, v in enumerate(p):
            d[f"Value_Depend_On_ID_{i}"] = v
        out.append(d)

    return pd.DataFrame(out)


x = (
    df.groupby("issue")
    .apply(group_func, include_groups=False)
    .reset_index(1, drop=True)
    .reset_index()
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   issue  Value_Depend_On_ID_0  Value_Depend_On_ID_1  Value_Depend_On_ID_2
0      1                    33                    34                  35.0
1      2                    33                    34                   NaN
```